# Playwright waitForResponse as I evaluate page

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I am trying to intercept XHR resources as I lazyload content with Playwright.

I am using this, which works well the first time.

```
const content = await page.waitForResponse((response) =>
  response.url().includes('somedata.json')
)

const { data } = await content.json()
```

The problem is that when I lazyload the content by scrolling, it always gets the same `content` and does not load the new `somedata.json` that gets generated as I keep scrolling.

```
const results = await page.evaluate(async (data) => {
  let arr = []

  for (let i = 0; i < document.body.scrollHeight; i += 100) {
    arr.push(...Object.values(data))
    window.scrollTo(0, i)
  }

  return arr
}, data)
```

Is there a way to trigger a new interception inside `page.evaluate`?

Comment: Could you wait for an element in the UI to load instead? This would mimic the user a bit more too.

Comment: Instead of what? I still need to scrol the page